# Скрипт при открытии в мобильной версии

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Нужно чтобы, при открытии мобильной версии Гугл таблицы (на моб.телефоне), скрипт проскролил/активировал последнюю ячейку таблицы

может кто подскажет по моему вопросу.?!

У меня есть триггер на открытие таблицы - запускается скрипт (активация ячейки внизу таблицы).
Дело в том, что в десктоп версии Гугл таблицы такое проделывается легко (все работает), например:

```html
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      ss.setActiveSelection('A'+ss.getLastRow());
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

Но этот скрипт не срабатывает в моб.телефоне (ввиду наверно урезанных возможностей моб. версии таблицы).

Но всё-таки надеюсь - Знатоки что -то подскажут!

Answer (score 1):

Такого события в мобильной версии нет.